# How to remove dots and spaces in initials of a name

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have a pyspark dataframe with names like:

- J.J. Scott
- J. S. Joyce
- RV. Bradley Carter

Some of them contain dots and spaces between initials and some do not. How can they be converted to:

- JJ Scott
- JS Joyce
- RV Bradley Carter

(with no dots and spaces between initials and 1 space between initials and name)

I tried using the following but it only replaces dots and doesn't remove spaces between initials:

```
names_modified = names.withColumn("name_clean", regexp_replace("name", r"\.",""))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some further manipulations can be done using `transform`. The idea is to split the name using spaces, and recombine them by only adding spaces between strings that are longer than 1 char, such that initials will be combined without spaces.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

names_modified = names.withColumn(
    'name_clean',
    F.expr("""
        concat_ws('',
            transform(
                split(replace(name, '.', ''), ' '),
                (x, i) -> case when i = 0 then x
                               when length(x) > 1 then concat(' ', x)
                               else x
                          end
            )
        )
    """)
)

names_modified.show()
+------------------+-----------------+
|              name|       name_clean|
+------------------+-----------------+
|        J.J. Scott|         JJ Scott|
|       J. S. Joyce|         JS Joyce|
|RV. Bradley Carter|RV Bradley Carter|
+------------------+-----------------+
```